# Converting Seismic Shot Points into polyline for linear distance for each Tract using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, line

I have Seismic shot points (receivers and source points) that I am trying to convert from Points into a polyline for linear distance for each Tract in ArcView 10.1.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what "shot points" are and how they relate to tracts.  Thanks.

Comment: Are the receivers/source points related somehow so you know the start and the end of the line? If so you can use a search cursor to iterate through the points and an insert cursor to create the line geometry. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polyline/018z00000008000000/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ArcGIS tool [Points To Line (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000) to create line features from points:

[image]